# Access html form id from javascript which is written in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, html

In my application id have an html form.

```
<form id="abc_form" method="post">
</form>
```

I want to give action to this form ans then submit it.
Something like:

```
 abc_form.action='full path of next page'
 abc_form.submit();
```

But I want to do this in C# since the path that I form is from the code in C#.
Is there any way to do it in C#? or even in javascript that is written in C#.I tried to do in the following way.But I could not succeed.The error that I get is cannotfind abc_form.

```
  Response.Write("<script> $([id$='abc_form']).action='" + myloc + "';</script>");
  Response.Write("<script>abc_form.submit();</script>");
```

What should I do? Please help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. Please elaborate. This is completely against web forms model. There might be a cleaner way to solve this.

Comment: I am trying to submit a form to amazon mechanical turk from my application which is in C# to mturk.So for that I have to do different things and then finally contruct a URL (which will be the action of my form) that tells amazon mturk that the job has been completed.Hence this question.

Comment: tried this? https://aws.amazon.com/code/923

Answer (score 0):

Why not use abc_form.ClientId in C#? or change the clientidmode to static in ASPX page. so u can use it in javascript as is.

---

Sometimes all the lovely libraries don't work (atleast not for me) :(

You can try the following in C#:

```
string jsCode = @"
                 var abc_form = document.getElementById('abc_form');
                 abc_form.action='full path of next page';
                 abc_form.submit();
                 ";

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), jsCode, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.But I need to submit my html form in a function of c# itself.So it is like: there are set of things that I do to construct a path and then I have to give this path to the form as action and submit that form.And as far as I know, abc_form.ClientId is written in javascript in order to get access of those things that run at server side.I cannot set the runat='server' for this form since asp.net should have only 1 form.Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Ahh I see, my bad, I misread the question. I will update with relevant solution or delete it.

Comment: thank you for the code.I tired to execute the code but it stil cannot find abc_form.So it still gives me the error :Cannot set property 'action' of null .